# Audio player becomes unresponsive after paused for a minute

Tags: just-audio

Building an audio streaming app using just_audio and audio_service. It uses an HLS url stream to get the audio. When audio is playing and the device is locked the controls will show on the lock screen and work properly using play/pause. However if the audio is paused for around a minute or longer the play button is tapped the lock screen controls will turn grey. I'll then open the app and try tapping play in the view and the Audio processing state will change to idle and nothing else happens.

I'm wonder if it has to do with the HLS stream at all. The amount of time that the player has to be paused before it "breaks" varies, but does seem to be consistent with the amount of audio that has buffered. So play/pause works fine if the amount of time the audio has been paused is less than the buffered amount, but if it passes then I encounter this issue.

As far as I can tell, nothing useful is logged at the time the audio player stops working, nor when tapping play/pause while in this state. I've tried to see if the OS kills the audio player maybe so I could re-init, but that doesn't seem to be the case either.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Is this Android or iOS or macOS?

Comment: iOS, the problem doesn't seem to happen on Android, but I also haven't tested nearly as much. If I set it up so tapping Play always calls playMediaItem, then when it "breaks" I will get an exception "Could not connect to server" so maybe it has to do with iOS not allowing a connection? Maybe there is a temp work around where I can re-init something in these cases to get it working again? I tried initAudioService(), but no luck there.

Comment: Can you try setting `canUseNetworkResourcesForLiveStreamingWhilePaused` to `true` in `DarwinLoadControl`?

Comment: I've had that setting from the beginning.

Done a bit more testing. It doesn't happen at all while the app is open, it only occurs after locking the phone and then either interacting with the lock screen player or opening the app and interacting there. It seems like there's a disconnect between the audio going to background, being paused for sometime and then trying to play it again.

Comment: What could be helpful for my situation is setting a timer to remove/dispose the background audio controls (Lock Screen and control center). I've tried setting a timer in my audio handler file, but it doesn't fire while the device is locked. Maybe there is a state I can listen to instead? This issue only occurs when the Lock Screen controls come into play. if I keep the app open the entire time, everything works great.

Comment: I found out part of the issue was the session timeout on the url we were using. We were able to up that from 45 seconds to 5 minutes. Not sure how it helps, but it's allowing us to stay paused on the live stream on lock the screen for long periods without breaking. However that introduced another issue where when we switched audio to a non-HLS it wouldn't connect. As a work around when calling playMediaItem I am disposing the audio player and then re-init it. with those changes things are working now.

Comment: Interesting, you might consider posting (and accepting) that answer below for future reference.

Comment: I think I'll do that. although it's probably not the best to keep reinitializing the audio player right? I might try updating the code to use the SwitchAudioHandler, I just don't have time to do it right now. I think that would be the better solution for my specific case (having a live stream using HLS and another view that plays only audio files from a url that appears to be another player, but uses the same one and simply updates the mediaItem)

Comment: You don't really need to use SwitchAudioHandler since that's merely an architectural thing. It is possible to maintain multiple audio player instances within a single handler and implement your switching logic within that one handler yourself. If you really want to know why iOS is behaving the way it is, you might want to clone the audio_service git repo and insert your own debug logs into it to see exactly where the original code was failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out, however, I'm not sure it's best solution.

One part is the provider for our HLS url for the live stream was able to increase the session timeout from 45 seconds to 5 minutes. There doesn't seem to be any negative behavior in doing this. It somehow prevents the background controls from breaking (greying out) when the audio has been paused for more then a minute (this varies and doesn't seem directly related to the session timeout, so maybe some magic iOS is doing too, who knows).

The other part is when a user locks their device and interacts with the background player something breaks to the point where if they go back into the app and try to switch the audio source something fails deep in the audio player. To "fix" this, when switching from the live stream to a non-HLS url I am now calling dispose on the audio player in the handler then re-initializing it.

This has solved my problem, but I think a better solution exists. For my specific case, using the SwitchAudioHandler may be that better solution, but I haven't had the time to try it.